# How to check if a point is inside an ellipsoid?

Tags: algorithm, 3d, geometry, distance, volume

We have a point in three dimensional space and an ellipsoid centered at the point of origin. The ellipsoid is upstanding meaning there is no rotation applied. It has three different radii, or how you call it for an ellipsoid.

How can I easily check whether a point is inside the volume covered by the ellipsoid? For example for a sphere, which I had before, I simply used the distance of the point vector and checked if it was smaller than the radius. But it becomes more tricky for ellipsoids.

For my use case an approximation would be fine, too.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The [standard equation of an ellipsoid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipsoid) centered at the origin and aligned with the axes is

> (x/a)<sup>2</sup> + (y/b)<sup>2</sup> + (z/c)<sup>2</sup> = 1

(The ellipsoid passes through points (a, 0, 0), (0, b, 0) and (0, 0, c).) Just plug in values for (x, y, z) for your point and if it's less than 1, the point is inside the ellipsoid.

Note that in any implementation there is likely to be some roundoff error. The effect of this is that points very close to the boundary of the ellipsoid may end up misclassified. (Here, "very close" depends on the accuracy of the number representation you are using--double precision has smaller roundoff error than floating point, for instance--and on the relative magnitudes of `a`, `b`, and `c`.) Depending on your application, you may need to organize your logic to deal with such uncertainties. There's a lot of literature on this subject, which is easy to tap into with a few web searches.

Comment: what if its not centred about the origin?

Comment: @TheJackal - Then simply subtract the origin from the point coordinates in the equation: `((x - cx)/a)^2`, etc.